# fflush() is not working in Linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I used the fflush() in Linux GCC but it did not work. Are there any alternatives for that function? Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
  char ch='y';
  while(ch=='y')
  {
    int a;
    printf("Enter some value:");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Do you want to continue?");
    scanf("%c",&ch)
  }
```

The output that I got is:

```
Enter some value: 10
```

Then the program ends. That's all. What can I do in Linux? Is there an alternative function?

Comment: Remember that flushing `stdin` is actually undefined behavior. Don't do it.

Comment: Don't `fflush(stdin)`. Instead change `scanf()` to `fgets()`.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Stefan I just tried to flush the input stream using fflush(). In windows it works, but in linux it does not work...

Comment: @sundar Yes, but why do you want to flush the input stream?  It's impossible to recommend an alternative unless you say what you need the programme to do.

Comment: `fflush()` is an undefined operation on input streams. Some compilers may, _as an extension_, provide support for this undefined behavior. I would not recommend relying on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using fflush(stdin)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't use fflush, use this function instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void clean_stdin(void)
{
    int c;
    do {
        c = getchar();
    } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

`fflush(stdin)` depends of the implementation, but this function always works. In C, it is considered bad practice to use `fflush(stdin)`.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is a bad practice, not `fflush`. ;)

Comment: @md5 what do you mean "not fflush".  do you mean fflush is good practice? or fflush with no parameters doesn't exist?

Comment: @barlop: `fflush` might be useful, e.g. with an output stream: `fflush(stdout)` forces the output to be written (see http://paste.awesom.eu/4dym). Here it is _not_ an undefined behavior.

Comment: Can you explain how this works instead of just saying "dont use that, use this, it works"?

Comment: While this will work if the buffer has some input. If it will be empty getchar() will force the console to ask for additional input meaning you will need to click additional "enter" key to create a newline. Maybe fflush(stdin) is a bad practice, but it prevents this problem

Answer (score 7):

One that always works on Linux:

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void clean_stdin()
{
        int stdin_copy = dup(STDIN_FILENO);
        /* remove garbage from stdin */
        tcdrain(stdin_copy);
        tcflush(stdin_copy, TCIFLUSH);
        close(stdin_copy);
}
```

You can use *tcdrain* and *tcflush* not only for in/out/err fd.

Comment: Why are you creating a duplicate of STDIN_FILENO?

Answer (score 5):

The behavior of `fflush` is not defined for input streams ([online 2011 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)):

> **7.21.5.2 The `fflush` function**
> **Synopsis**
> 1
>
> ```
>     #include <stdio.h>
>     int fflush(FILE *stream);
> ```
>
> **Description**
> 2 If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent
>  operation was not input, the `fflush` function causes any unwritten data for that stream
> to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is
>  undefined.
> 3 If `stream` is a null pointer, the `fflush` function performs this flushing action on all
>    streams for which the behavior is defined above.
> **Returns**
> 4
> The `fflush` function sets the error indicator for the stream and returns EOF if a write
> error occurs, otherwise it returns zero.

Comment: `fflush` on input streams is not defined in POSIX.1-2001, but **it is** defined in POSIX.1-2008

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem while working on LINUX and an alternative solution of this problem can be that you define a dummy character lets say `char dummy;`
and put a `scanf()` to scan it just before your actual input takes place. This worked for me. I hope it would work for you too.

Answer (score 1):

`fflush()` doesn't do much for input streams but since `scanf()` never returns this doesn't matter. `scanf()` blocks because the terminal window doesn't send anything to the C program until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

You have two options:

1. Type `10` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Put the terminal into raw mode.

The second option has many drawbacls like you will lose editing capabilities, so I suggest to read the input line by line.

Answer (score 1):

You must include  and use __fpurge(whatever you want) instead.

Salute from argentina

Comment: You should explain why you need to include that, instead of just saying you do.

Answer (score 0):

Use getchar() instead, after scanf

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char ans='y';
int a;
while(ans=='y'||ans=='Y')
    {

     printf("Type a number:-");
     scanf("%d",&a);
     printf("square of number = %d\nwant to enter 
     number again(y/n)?\nANS=",a*a); 
     scanf("%s",&ans);//use %s in place of %c
     }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add some description with your answer

Answer (score -1):

By using `bzero();` system call in Linux we can flush the previous stored value.
Please read the manual page of `bzero();` by typing in terminal `man bzero`.
try this example

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
  char buf[]={'y'};
  int num;
  while(buf[0]=='y')
  {
    printf("enter number");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("square of %d is %d\n",num,num*num);
    bzero(buf, 1);
    printf("want to enter y/n");
    scanf("%s",&buf[0]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code will cause a buffer overflow on the `scanf("%s"` line. Also, `buf[0] = 0;` would be less error-prone than `bzero(buf, 1)`.