# What is the use of fflush(stdin) in c programming?

Tags: c

I have the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char ans[8];
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        printf("\n What is the unit of traffic ?");
        scanf("%s",ans);
        fflush(stdin);

        if(stricmp(ans,"Earlang")==0)
        {
            printf("\nAnswer is correct");
            exit(1);
        }
        else
            if(i<3)
            printf("\n Try Again!\n");
    }
    printf("\n Nunit of traffic is Earlang:");
}
```

What is the use of `fflush(stdin)` in this program?

Comment: @MitchWheat As you (should) know, a lot of docs will not mention `fflush(stdin)`, since it only has a defined behavior on some platforms. It's perfectly normal to be puzzled by this at first (but there must be a ton of duplicate questions on SO, e.g. [Using fflush(stdin)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin)).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin

Answer (score 27):

It's not in standard C, so the behavior is undefined.

Some implementation uses it to clear `stdin` buffer.

From C11 7.21.5.2 *The fflush function*, `fflush` works only with output/update stream, not input stream.

> If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent
>   operation was not input, the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream
>   to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Comment: +1. This is perfectly right, from the view of the C standard. Some implemetations give semantics to `fflush()`ing an input stream, but that is an extension.

Answer (score 11):

it clears `stdin` buffer before reading. From the man [page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush):

> For output streams, fflush() forces a write of all user-space buffered
>   data for the given output or update stream via the stream's underlying
>   write function. **For input streams, fflush() discards any buffered data
>   that has been fetched from the underlying file, but has not been
>   consumed by the application.**

Note: This is Linux-specific, using `fflush()` on input streams is undefined by the standard, however, most implementations behave the same as in Linux.

Comment: in the above program , even though  fflush(stdin) is not written , the program will execute , but how fflush(stdin) will be helpfull.please suggest.

Comment: @user2526830 I'm not sure what you're saying, but like I said it clears the buffer before reading again.

Comment: @user2526830 It will make sure that the program always executes properly on different machines, running different processes, under different system loads and NOT just on your machine.

Comment: The man page is actually a bit misleading: it describes the (POSIX-mandated, not just Linux-specific) behavior for *seekable* input streams. The Linux `fflush` does exactly nothing when called on stdin (well, it attempts an `lseek`, catches `ESPIPE`, and then does exactly nothing)

Answer (score 6):

It's an unportable way to remove all data from the input buffer till the next newline.
I've seen it used in cases like that:

```
char c;
char s[32];
puts("Type a char");
c=getchar();
fflush(stdin);
puts("Type a string");
fgets(s,32,stdin);
```

Without the `fflush()`, if you type a character, say "a", and the hit enter, the input buffer contains "a\n", the `getchar()` peeks the "a", but the "\n" remains in the buffer, so the next `fgets()` will find it and return an empty string without even waiting for user input.

However, note that this use of `fflush()` is unportable. I've tested right now on a Linux machine, and it does not work, for example.

Comment: In linux use:

#include <stdio.h>
void clean_stdin(void)
{
    int c;
    do {
        c = getchar();
    } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
}

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17319153/1925162