# C: Clearing STDIN

Tags: c, input, buffer, stdin, fflush

basically in codeblocks for windows before each printf I have "fflush(stdin);" which works. When I copied my code to Linux, it doesn't work, nor does any of the alternatives for "fflush(stdin);" that I've found. No matter which way I seem to do it, the input doesn't seem to be clearing in the buffer or something in my code is incorrect.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
   char pbuffer[10], qbuffer[10], kbuffer[10];
   int p=0, q=0, k=0;
   int r, i, Q, count, sum;
   char a[3];
   a[0]='y';
   while(a[0]=='y' || a[0]=='Y')
   {
      printf("Enter a p value: \n");
      fgets(pbuffer, sizeof(pbuffer), stdin);
      p = strtol(pbuffer, (char **)NULL, 10);

      printf("Enter a q value: \n");
      fgets(qbuffer, sizeof(qbuffer), stdin);
      q = strtol(qbuffer, (char **)NULL, 10);

      printf("Enter a k value: \n");
      fgets(kbuffer, sizeof(kbuffer), stdin);
      k = strtol(kbuffer, (char **)NULL, 10);

      while(p<q+1)
      {
         Q=p;
         sum=0;
         count=0;
         while(Q>0)
         {
            count++;
            r = Q%10;
            sum = sum + pow(r,k);
            Q = Q/10;
         }

         if ( p == sum && i>1 && count==k )
         {
            printf("%d\n",p);

         }
         p++;
         a[0]='z';
      }
      while((a[0]!='y') && (a[0]='Y') && (a[0]!='n') && (a[0]!='N'))
      {
         printf("Would you like to run again? (y/n) ");
         fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin);
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @PaulR , you are I belive mistaken. Conforming to
These functions are nonstandard and not portable. The function fpurge() was introduced in 4.4BSD and is not available under Linux. The function __fpurge() was introduced in Solaris, and is present in glibc 2.1.95 and later. http://linux.die.net/man/3/fpurge

Comment: With `a` defined as a `char` your input is **WRONG** (`scanf(" %s", &a);`): it will try to write at least the `'\0'` character in the memory position after where `a` is located. That memory position does not belong to you.

Comment: @Satya: you may be right - I'll delete my comment.

Comment: Please note that this behavior of `fflush` is not that widely supported and not really compatible with the usual meaning of "flush".  There's really no standard, portable way to clear the input stream without reading from it.

Comment: BTW: `pow(r,k);` is likely a problem.  Lots of SO posts on that one. Use something like `unsigned powuu(unsigned x, unsigned y) { unsigned z = 1u; unsigned base = x; while (y) { if (y & 1u) { z *= base; }  y >>= 1u;  base *= base;  } return z; }`

Answer (score 2):

Calling `fflush(stdin)` is not standard, so the behavior is undefined (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18170435/335858) for more information).

Rather than calling `fflush` on `stdin`, you could call `scanf`, passing a format string instructing the function to read everything up to and including the newline `'\n'` character, like this:

```
scanf("%*[^\n]%1*[\n]");
```

The asterisk tells `scanf` to ignore the result.

Another problem is calling `scanf` to read a character into variable `a` with the format specifier of `" %s"`: when the user enters a non-empty string, null terminator creates buffer overrun, causing undefined behavior (`char a` is a buffer of one character; string `"y"` has two characters - `{'y', '\0'}`, with the second character written past the end of the buffer). You should change `a` to a buffer that has several characters, and pass that limit to `scanf`:

```
char a[2];
do {
    printf("Would you like to run again? (y/n) \n")
    scanf("%1s", a);
} while(a[0] !='y' && a[0] !='Y' && a[0]!='n' && a[0]!='N' );
}
```

Comment: When I add that scanf function, it gets a bit more whacky. It seem that the more characters I enter, it becomes input for the future input(q and k value).

Comment: @AndrewRicci The space in front of `%s` in `" %s"` looks highly suspicious, too.

Comment: Or he could keep `a` as a single `char` and use `" %c"`.

Comment: `scanf("%*[^\n]\n");` will scan non-`'\n'`, and if finding one will scan for _any number_ of white-space and will _not_ return until a following non-white-space is entered.  Better to use `scanf("%*[^\n]%1*[\n]");`

Comment: Hmmmm.  `scanf(any_format, ...);` has the problem that if there is no input presently in the input buffer to flush, `scanf()` will not return until there is _something_.  This might not meet OP's needs.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the need for flushing the input buffer.

OP is on the right track using `fgets()` rather than `scanf()` for input,  OP should continue that approach with:

```
char a;
while(a !='y' && a !='Y' && a!='n' && a!='N' ) {

  printf("Would you like to run again? (y/n) \n");
  if (fgets(kbuffer, sizeof(kbuffer), stdin) == NULL) 
    Handle_EOForIOerror();

  int cnt = sscanf(kbuffer, " %c", &a); // Use %c, not %s
  if (cnt == 0) 
    continue; // Only white-space entered
  }
```

Best to not use `scanf()` as it tries to handle user IO and parsing in one shot and does neither that well.

---

Certain present OP's woes stem from `fgets()` after `scanf(" %s", &a);`  (which is UB as it should be `scanf(" %c", &a);`.  Mixing `scanf()` with `fgets()` typically has the problem that the `scanf(" %c", &a);` leaves the <kbd>Enter</kbd> or `'\n'` in the input buffer obliging the code to want to flsuh the input buffer before the next `fgets()`.  Else that `fgets()` gets the stale `'\n'` and not a new line of info.

By *only* using `fgets()` for user IO, there need for flushing is negated.

---

Sample `fgets()` wrapper

```
char *prompt_fgets(const char *prompt, char dest, long size) {
  fputs(prompt, stdout);
  char *retval = fgets(dest, size, stdin);
  if (retval != NULL) {
    size_t len = strlen(dest);
    if (len > 1 && dest[len-1] == '\n') { // Consume trailing \n
      dest[--len] = '\0';
    }
    else if (len + 1 == dest) {  // Consume extra char
      int ch;
      do {
        ch == fgetc(stdin);
      } while (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF);
    }
  return retval;
  }
```

Comment: You're right, I don't know why I even though to mix it...anyhow, as I fixed that, my problem still persists where after the first run through and choosing to run again, I'm prompted with
"Enter a p value" and "Enter a q value:" directly below it waiting for prompt.

Comment: Suspect you are using something like `printf("Would you like to run again? (y/n) \n"); if (fgets(buffer, 2, stdin) ...` where `buffer` is too small.  (Needs to be at least 3.) Otherwise I'd would have to see your corrected code.  See if the buffer was too small, the `'\n'` for this prompt is still left in the input buffer and the next `fgets()` takes that in without waiting for another line of input - hence the 2 prompts of  "Enter a p value" and "Enter a q value:",

Comment: I just updated my code. It is still acting weird. Generally when I input a larger set of characters it ether skips prompts and loops over again. I may just start over, I'm wondering if you could point me into a direction of secure ways of coding/handling input.

Comment: 1) Not good to alter your post in such a ways that it makes answers look like they are addressing the wrong issues.  Better to append your changes or even post a new question if this one is answered.  2) Suggest getting your user input via a helper function like in this edited answer.  Likely more than you need.  The idea is to encapsulate user prompt/input in one general purpose function.  After each prompt, user input up to a `'\n'` should be consumed

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is more difficult than it seems.

My interpretation of what you are trying to do is disable type ahead so that if the user types some characters while your program is processing other stuff, they don't appear at the prompt.  This is actually quite difficult to do because it is an OS level function.

You could do a non blocking read  on the device before printing the prompt until you get EWOULDBLOCK in errno.  Or the [tcsetattr function family](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tcsetattr) might help.  It looks like there is a way to drain input for a file descriptor in there, but it might interact badly with fgets/fscanf

A better idea is not to worry about it at all.  Unix users are used to having type ahead and what you want would be unexpected behaviour for them.