# how do I input values into a structure using pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, structure, function-pointers

I have a small problem with this program I'm writing, I'm trying to input data into a structure using a pointer but the compiler just gives me an error stating:  "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type"

the function of the program is simple:
a program that uses functions to input data into a structure using pointers

heres the code:
the main function simply calls the input function and passes the structure pointer as an argument

```
void input(struct test *ptr)
{
printf("Enter: \n");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%s",&ptr->entry);

}

void print(struct test *ptr)
{

}

int main()
{
    int counter;
    struct test
    {
        char entry[20];

    }p[4];
    struct test *ptr=p;
    ptr=&p;

    for(counter=0;counter<=4;counter++)
        {
            input(ptr);
            ptr++;
        }
    return 1;
}
```

The print function is still empty.

Comment: "The print function is still empty." Yes, it is. We're not going to write your code for you.  What is your specific question?

Comment: And you don't want <=4, as you'll access one off the end of your `p` array.

Comment: "the compiler just gives me an error stating: "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type"" On what line? Help us help you...

Comment: I edited the original post stating my question but anyways my question is how do I enter values into my structure using pointers?  "scanf("%c",&ptr->entry);" seems to cause an error.

Comment: @Slaine `scanf("%s",ptr->entry);`

Comment: @Gopi I edited that line to that I still get the same error.

Comment: [`fflush(stdin)` is Undefined Behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170410/what-is-the-use-of-fflushstdin-in-c-programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scanning a string using `&` is not required.
A string should be scanned using `%s` not `%c`.
Filling your empty print. Preferably change your function name `print` to something else.

Check the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
    struct test
    {
        char entry[20];

    }p[4];

void input(struct test *ptr)
{
printf("Enter: \n");
scanf("%s",ptr->entry);
return;
}

void print(struct test *ptr)
{
int i;
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    printf("%s\n",ptr[i].entry);
}
return;
}
int main()
{
    int counter;

    struct test *ptr=p;

    for(counter=0;counter<4;counter++)
        {
            input(ptr);
            ptr++;
        }
        print(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First problem is that `struct test` is defined only inside your "main" function and is not accessible to `input` or `print`.  Define it outside all the functions.

Then you want to scan a string, not a character, so you need `"%s"`. Actually "%19s" so if the input is too long you don't walk off the end of the entry array (Hat tip to @BLUEPIXY)

And `ptr->entry` is the address of where you want to put the string so you don't need `&ptr->entry` but `ptr->entry`

You assign to `ptr` twice in `main`. The second is wrong (again, `p` is the address of the array of structs, so you have it right in the initialisation. The assignment of `&p` is wrong.

Finally, your for-loop executes 5 times (0,1,2,3,4) and the last iteration accesses one off the end of your 4-element `p` array

Putting that altogether:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test
{
    char entry[20];
};

void input(struct test *ptr)
{
    printf("Enter: \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%19s", ptr->entry);
}

void print(struct test *ptr)
{

}

int main()
{
    int counter;
    struct test p[4];
    struct test *ptr=p;

    for(counter=0;counter<4;counter++)
    {
        input(ptr);
        ptr++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Oops, missed actually changing the `%c`. Thanks