# Assigning values to an array after malloc causes crash

Tags: c++, c, arrays, malloc

I got a little assignment to do with C, but I can't seam to fill up an array that I allocated memory to. The code is like so..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int *x, *y, n, m, i;

    printf("Enter lenght of arrays x and y (separated by space): ");
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &m); fflush(stdin);

    if (x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * n) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (y = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * m) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Enter %d values for X array (separated by space) ", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", x + i);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Enter %d values for Y array (separated by space): ", m);
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        scanf("%d", y + i);
    } //the two for's were originally in a function, I tried using the code like this as well
    return 0;
}
```

I also tried running scanf("%d", x[i]); but nothing works. Every time I hit Enter after typing in the array for X the program crashes. By the way, originally no fflush(stdin) was there originally, I added them because I thought that the input took \0 as one of the values and that created errors.

Thank you for reading! :)

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour. Also, [........](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95ebf479afe96a37)

Comment: How is it an undefined behaviour (not trying to be rude, I'm just new to using it, so any info is welcome!), we used it in college, from what I got it "swallows" any input the computer registered so far, so functions like gets(); don't take inputs like \0.

EDIT: and when I fixed the malloc inside the if (adding brackets), the code worked! thanks! If you want put it in the answers, and I'll give you a star/arrow up.

Comment: A college course in C propagating incorrect information, bad practices standards violations? Unthinkable!

Comment: Just informationally, is there an alternative to fflush? Because, if I use, say: printf("Type in your name: "); gets(name); I had moments when the name would just take the value \0 and not actually give the user the option of inputting something. By the way, I agree with you Kerrek, thus why I rely on internet information more than college one.

Comment: @NemanjaT, It's undefined because the standard clearly says something along the lines of "fflush(stdin) is undefined behaviour." Anyway, NEVER use `gets`. It's so bad that it's been removed from C and C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code has a bunch of misplaced braces and parentheses, especially in the if statements.  You have to wrap the assignments in parenthesis before doing the comparison, else they're misassigned.  Try this, it compiled and worked for me:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
int *x, *y, n, m, i;

printf("Enter lenght of arrays x and y (separated by space): ");
scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);

if ((x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * n)) == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error!\n");
    exit(1);
}
if ((y = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * m)) == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error!\n");
    exit(1);
}

printf("Enter %d values for X array (separated by space) ", n);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    scanf("%d", x + i);

printf("Enter %d values for Y array (separated by space): ", m);
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    scanf("%d", y + i);
 //the two for's were originally in a function, I tried using the code like this as well
return 0;
}
```

And like everyone else says, don't use fflush(stdin)

Answer (score 2):

The use of `fflush(stdin)` is probably causing the crash, since it's undefined behavior in standard C.

Take a look at this answer [what is the use of fflush(stdin) in c programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170410/what-is-the-use-of-fflushstdin-in-c-programming)

Comment: Nah, Chris solved it, inside the if statement, it didn't question if malloc didn't assign memory (didn't put enough brackets). Stdin overall worked fine when I fixed that.

Comment: @NemanjaT: I still strongly recommend that you stop using `fflush(stdin)` since it's undefined behavior, which basically means "not guaranteed to work".  It may be a no-op on your system, but it's likely going to cause someone a great deal of pain one day because it crashes in their specific configuration.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're aiming at, alright. But as I said in my question comments: Just informationally, is there an alternative to fflush? Because, if I use, say: printf("Type in your name: "); gets(name); I had moments when the name would just take the value \0 and not actually give the user the option of inputting something. By the way, I agree with you Kerrek, thus why I rely on internet information more than college one.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compile the programm with Visual Studio 2013 and got 2 errors at the lines with malloc:
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'bool' to 'int *'
After i fixed both lines by

```
 if ((x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * n)) == NULL){
```

or

```
if (x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * n)){
```

the program runs without any problems.

I don't understand why you could compile the code, but it does the following:

compare (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * n) == NULL result is false
and now set y = false and y does not point to the allocated array.