# lvalue error on the 10th line

Tags: c, compiler-errors, lvalue

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main ()
{
    clrscr ()   ;
    char a  [5];
    puts ("K?");
    gets (a);
    fflush (stdin);
    if (a = ("K"))
    {
        puts (a);
    }
    else
    {
        puts ("BAE");
    }
    getch ();
}
```

The 10th line shows an Lvalue error while compiling, please help. this is my first program ever and this is my first day ever on coding and I'm self teaching.

Answer (score 1):

- `fflush(stdin)` is [**Undefined Behavior**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170410/what-is-the-use-of-fflushstdin-in-c-programming)
- the **comparison** operator in C is a `==`; `=` is the **assignment** operator. You can't assign anything to an array, so an error is thrown
- you can compare strings using [`strcmp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) from `<string.h>`; `==` just [compares their addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

Comment: Thanks, the code compiles now but whatever I type, the result is "BAE" instead of (a). please help.

Comment: `strcmp()` returns `0` if the strings equal. You sure you tested that?

Comment: Oh I'm a retard, I get it. Got it working now. Thanks!

Comment: On StackOverflow, you thank by accepting an answer. But you're welcome anyway. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that instead of the assignment in the if statement

```
if (a = ("K"))
```

you mean a comparison.

Nevertheless arrays  do not have the comparison operator. You have to compare arrays element by element yourself. For character arrays there is function `strcmp` declared in header `<string.h>`. 
Thus the valid code can look like

Also you should not use fflush function with standard input. Otherwise the program has undefined behaviour,

```
#include <string.h>

//...

if ( strcmp( a, "K" ) == 0 )
//...
```

Comment: Arrays **do** have a comparison operator when they are implicitly converted into an address.

Comment: @cad  You are wrong. Arrays do not have the comparison operator., It is pointers that have the comparison operator., Pointers and arrays are different types.

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in this line

```
if (a = ("K"))
```

First, you are using `=` where you meant `==`. But that is wrong anyway, you cannot test for string equality in C. It has to be something like this, which tests the first character of the string and its terminator

```
if (a[0] == 'K' && a[1] == '\0')
```

or, you can use a library function

```
#include <string.h>
...
if (strcmp(a, "K") == 0) {
    // are the same string.
}
```