# fgets taking struct pointer inside function crashes

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm having trouble getting a struct `pointer` to take user input through `fgets` inside a function in a c program; I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The `getInput()` function is where the crash is occurring. I'm first trying to assign memory to the where the name is going to be stored with

```
*stu->name = (char*)malloc(N_LENGTH);
```

then getting input from the user with

```
fgets(*stu->name, N_LENGTH, stdin);
```

The program crashes during the first line and also the second line.

Sorry if I'm breaking any rules as this is my first time on the site.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define UNIT 100
#define HOUSE 1000
#define THRESH 12
#define DISCOUNT 10
#define NUM_PERSONS 5
#define N_LENGTH 30


struct student
{
    char *name;
    char campus;
    int userUnit;
};

void getInput(struct student *stu);
int amountCalc(struct student *stu);
void printOutput(struct student stu, int total);

int main()
{
    int total[NUM_PERSONS];
    int averageTotal=0;
    struct student tempStudent;
    struct student students[NUM_PERSONS];
    struct student *sPtr = &tempStudent;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < NUM_PERSONS; i++)
    {
        getInput(sPtr);
        students[i]=tempStudent;
        total[i]=amountCalc(sPtr);
        averageTotal+=total[i];
    };

    for (i=0; i < NUM_PERSONS; i++)
    {
        printOutput(students[i], total[i]);
    };

    printf("\nThe average tuition cost for these %d students is $%.2f.\n",
            NUM_PERSONS, averageTotal/(NUM_PERSONS*1.0));
    return 0;
}

void getInput(struct student *stu)
{
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter student name: ");
        *stu->name = (char*)malloc(N_LENGTH);
        fgets(*stu->name, N_LENGTH, stdin);

        printf("Enter y if student lives on campus, n otherwise: ");
        scanf(" %s", &stu->campus);

        printf("Enter current unit count: ");
        scanf(" %d", &stu->userUnit);

        printf("\n");
}

int amountCalc(struct student *stu)
{
        int total;
        total=(stu->userUnit)*UNIT;

        if (stu->userUnit>THRESH) {
            total-=((stu->userUnit)-12)*DISCOUNT;
        };

        if (stu->campus=='y') {
            total+=HOUSE;
        };
        return total;
}

void printOutput(struct student stu, int total)
{
    printf("\nStudent name: %s\n", stu.name);
    printf("Amount due: $%d\n\n", total);
}
```

Comment: `*stu->name` -> `stu->name`.

Comment: Don't ignore compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Your allocation is wrong. True allocation is like this ;

```
void getInput(struct student *stu)
{
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter student name: ");
    stu->name = (char*)malloc(N_LENGTH);
    fgets(stu->name, N_LENGTH, stdin);

    printf("Enter y if student lives on campus, n otherwise: ");
    scanf(" %s", &stu->campus);

    printf("Enter current unit count: ");
    scanf(" %d", &stu->userUnit);

    printf("\n");
}
```

When you compile it, you can see as a warning. You should take care of all warnings. And casting malloc to (char *) is also unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `fflush(stdin)`. [See this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170410/what-is-the-use-of-fflushstdin-in-c-programming) I don't know if that causes the error but it is not defined in the C-standard so maybe your platform doesn't handle it!

The wrong allocation of memory is also a problem, look at @Hakkı Işık 's answer.