# I wonder why it doesn't work

Tags: c

I want this program show following.

```
Data input (Ctrl+Z to exit) : a
Data input (Ctrl+Z to exit) : b
Data input (Ctrl+Z to exit) : ^Z
sum : 2
```

But when I execute this code, `Data input (Ctrl+Z to exit) :` printed a few times.

For example, when I input 'A', of course 'A enter' 2 characters,then 2 times of "Data input (Ctrl+Z to exit) : " printed.

```
int main(void) 
{
    int cnt = 0;
    char input;

    while (1) {
        fputs("Data input (Ctrl+Z to exit) : ", stdout);
        input = getchar();

        if (input == EOF)
            break;

        fflush(stdin);
        cnt++;
    }
    printf("sum : %d", cnt);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not the most descriptive title!

Answer (score 0):

`getchar()` reads one character from the standard input, but you have multiple characters in `stdin` (character you've entered plus `\n` for enter key), so when it goes to the second iteration of the loop it reads that leftover `\n` from `stdin`.

Solution: instead of `fflush(stdin)` use `fpurge(stdin)` to clear all the buffered data.

**Edit:** your system may luck `fpurge` though, it's non-standard BSD function. On libc-based system (Linux, e.g.) there's `__fpurge` (see https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Flushing-Buffers.html)

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` and `fpurge` are both non-standard functions, so not portable.

Comment: @WeatherVane From `man fflush`:  `The fflush() function conforms to ISO/IEC 9899:1990 (``ISO C90'').` About `fpurge` I'm not sure.

Comment: Then please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18170435/4142924) which says *From C11 7.21.5.2 The fflush function, fflush works only with output/update stream, not input stream.*

Comment: @WeatherVane That I'm very aware of. I never proposed to use `fflush` on input stream, it was original poster, not me.

Comment: For `fpurge` please [read this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fpurge.3.html) which says *These functions are nonstandard and not portable.*

Comment: Yep, about `fpurge` I've said above "I'm not sure" :) Edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to read one char safely would be to use this function,

```
char readChar()
{
    char c;
    scanf(" %c" , &c);
    return c;
}
```

so in your code your can use

```
input = readChar();
```

and it will work.

Comment: I used both of solutions, but It doesn't work. Also, I cannot use 'fpurge' in my system.

Comment: I tested it on Linux using GCC compiler, it worked, what is your OS, and compiler ?