# Why is the last printf() not printing?

Tags: c, printf, fflush

I trying to create something where the user has to give certain numbers and at the end the program prints all the numbers with a space in between.
Everything is working, except the last `printf()`. I have tried to `fflush` in and out like the previous `scanf()` but nothing works.

Any suggestions? Here is the code:

```
printf("Give a round number:\n");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%d", &roundNumber);
fflush(stdin);

printf("Give a decimal number:\n");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%lf", &decimalNumber);
fflush(stdin);

printf("Give 2 round numbers separated by a ',' :\n");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%d,%d",firstRoundNumber,secondRoundNumber);
fflush(stdin);

printf("Your numbers: %d %lf %d %d\n", roundNumber, decimalNumber, firstRoundNumber, secondRoundNumber);
```

Comment: scanf("%d,%d",&firstRoundNumber,&secondRoundNumber);

Comment: `scanf("%d,%d",firstRoundNumber,secondRoundNumber); -> scanf("%d,%d",&firstRoundNumber,&secondRoundNumber);`

Comment: Also, 'fflush(stdin);' is UB.

Comment: Also, debug fail - stepping through would have shown that the printf() was not even reached.

Comment: Here is a handy link with the C11 standard referenced [**what is the use of fflush(stdin) in c programming**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170410/what-is-the-use-of-fflushstdin-in-c-programming). Also, if you just enclose your in-line code in comments in *backticks* (e.g. `\`stuff\``) it will be offset as fixed-width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote

```
scanf("%d,%d",firstRoundNumber,secondRoundNumber);
```

You forgot to use variables adresses for the last scanf :

```
scanf("%d,%d", &firstRoundNumber, &secondRoundNumber);
```