# Function fgets skips user input?

Tags: c

When I use the function `fgets`, the program skips the user input, effecting the rest of the program. An example program with this effect is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char firstDigit[2];
    char secondDigit[2];

    printf("Enter your first digit: ");
    fgets(firstDigit, 1, stdin);
    printf("\nEnter your second digit: ");
    fgets(secondDigit, 1, stdin);
    printf("\n\nYour first digit is %s and your second digit is %s.\n", firstDigit, secondDigit);
}
```

I then thought that maybe the problem was that `fgets` might be writing the newline, so I changed the code to account for that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char firstDigit[3];
    char secondDigit[3];

    printf("Enter your first digit: ");
    fgets(firstDigit, 2, stdin);
    printf("\nEnter your second digit: ");
    fgets(secondDigit, 2, stdin);
    printf("\n\nYour first digit is %c and your second digit is %c.\n", firstDigit[0], secondDigit[0]);
}
```

This time, the first input works properly, but the second input is skipped.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: @xing Doesn't the buffer need to be one character bigger to allow room for a `\0`?

Comment: Your input buffers are far too small.  Use `char firstLine[4096];` and `fgets(firstLine, sizeof(firstLine), stdin);` and then worry about what to do with any excess characters (ignoring them is probably appropriate).  It allows the user to type leading blanks, too.

Comment: Note that you should specify the full size of the buffer (typically `sizeof(array)` — though there's a conversion from `size_t` to `int` there).  You do not need to worry about 'off by one'; specify the full size because [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) won't overflow the buffer.  Using a size of 1 only allows `fgets()` to store a null byte — no data at all.  So it successfully reads nothing, rather fast, leaving the input stream unchanged.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Is it common practice to make your buffer size 4096?

Comment: POSIX says that the minimum value for the maximum size of a line `{LINE_MAX}` should be `{_POSIX2_LINE_MAX}` which is currently 2048.  I double that for my purposes.  See [`<limits.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html).  No, not everyone pays attention to this sort of detail, but it doesn't hurt unless you're on a very limited system. (When was the last time you were working on a machine with less than a gigabyte of main memory, which makes 4 KiB a minuscule fraction of the total?). I also do it for the shock value — to counter the problems that you have.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I would usually calculate the minimum amount of space reasonably needed, and assign that as my buffer size. Memory allocated but not used is basically wasted, right?

Comment: Yes, but 4 KiB is 0.0004% of 1 GiB, which is noise — actually, it is barely even that.  If you're writing an application and the buffer will be permanently allocated in `main()`, then maybe you worry about it, but if it is in a function called from `main()`, then you won't need to worry about it — it will be released.  And that way, you don't have to worry about dealing with the residue — someone who types `123456789012345678900987654321` when you wanted them to type `1`.  People will abuse your program — allowing plenty of space for input makes it harder for them to crash your program.

Comment: Incidentally, on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.6, using GCC 7.1.0, the following code produces 50 blank lines when given `/dev/null` as the input device: `#include <stdio.h>` — `int main(void)
{
    char buffer[1];
    int counter = 0;
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0 && counter++ < 50)
        puts(buffer);
    return 0;
}`

Comment: To add to the comments of @JonathanLeffler, it is likely that you will only need one large allocation for a user input buffer. As in the final example of my answer, you can use one input buffer, and store the relevant results in separate variables.

Comment: @DavidBowling I still like your method of clearing the stream if it isn't empty.

Answer (score 4):

`char firstDigit[2]` and `char secondDigit[2]` are not large enough to hold a digit, a newline character, and a null-terminator:

```
char firstDigit[3];
char secondDigit[3];
```

Then, the calls to `fgets()` need to specify the size of the buffer arrays:

```
fgets(firstDigit, sizeof firstDigit, stdin);
/* ... */
fgets(secondDigit, sizeof secondDigit, stdin);
```

When instead `fgets(firstDigit, 2, stdin);` is used, `fgets()` stores at most two characters, including the `\0` character, in `firstDigit[]`. This means that the `\n` character is still in the input stream, and this interferes with the second call to `fgets()`.

In answer to OP's comment, [How would you remove the unread characters from the input stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45644524/function-fgets-skips-user-input/45644573#comment78248960_45644573), a good start would be to use more generous allocations for `firstDigit[]` and `secondDigit[]`. For example, `char firstDigit[100]`, or even `char firstDigit[1000]` will be large enough that any expected input will be taken in by `fgets()`, leaving no characters behind in the input stream. To be more certain that the input stream is empty, a portable solution is to use the idiomatic loop:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
    continue;
}
```

Note here that it is necessary to check for `EOF`, since `getchar()` may return this value if the user signals end-of-file from the keyboard, or if `stdin` has been redirected, or in the unlikely event of an input error. But also note that this loop should only be used if there is at least a `\n` character still in the input stream. Before attempting to clear the input stream with this method, the input buffer should be checked for a newline; if it is present in the buffer, the input stream is empty and the loop should not be executed. In the code below, `strchr()` is used to check for the newline character. This function returns a null pointer if the sought-for character is not found in the input string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>           // for strchr()

int main(void)
{
    char firstDigit[3];       // more generous allocations would also be good
    char secondDigit[3];      // e.g., char firstDigit[1000];

    printf("Enter your first digit: ");
    fgets(firstDigit, sizeof firstDigit, stdin);

    /* Clear input stream if not empty */
    if (strchr(firstDigit, '\n') == NULL) {
        int c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
            continue;
        }
    }

    putchar('\n');
    printf("Enter your second digit: ");
    fgets(secondDigit, sizeof secondDigit, stdin);

    /* Clear input stream if not empty */
    if (strchr(secondDigit, '\n') == NULL) {
        int c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
            continue;
        }
    }

    puts("\n");
    printf("Your first digit is %c and your second digit is %c.\n",
           firstDigit[0], secondDigit[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

It may be even better to use a single `buffer[]` to store lines of input, and then to store individual characters in `char`s. You could also write a function to clear the input stream, instead of rewriting the same loop each time it is needed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>           // for strchr()

void clear_stdin(void);

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[1000];
    char firstDigit;
    char secondDigit;

    printf("Enter your first digit: ");
    fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
    firstDigit = buffer[0];

    /* Clear input stream if not empty */
    if (strchr(buffer, '\n') == NULL) {
        clear_stdin();
    }

    putchar('\n');
    printf("Enter your second digit: ");
    fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
    secondDigit = buffer[0];

    /* Clear input stream if not empty */
    if (strchr(buffer, '\n') == NULL) {
        clear_stdin();
    }

    puts("\n");
    printf("Your first digit is %c and your second digit is %c.\n",
           firstDigit, secondDigit);

    return 0;
}

void clear_stdin(void)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use this and type something like `123` for the first input, it uses `1` for the first digit, skips the second input and uses `3` for the second one?

Comment: @ericw31415-- That is because `sizeof firstDigit[]` is 3, so at most 3 characters will be stored in `firstDigit[]` _including the null-terminator_. So, `'1'` and`'2'` are stored, then `'\0'`. This leaves the `'3'` and `'\n'` to be picked up by the second call to `fgets()`.

Comment: @ericw31415 It should put `"12" in `firstDigit` and `"3\n"` in `secondDigit`

Comment: How would you remove the unread characters from the input stream?

Comment: @ericw31415-- I have added some comments and code to my answer to address your question about clearing the input stream.

Answer (score 3):

For the first case, `fgets(firstDigit, 1, stdin);` cannot read anything from the input because the buffer has a size of only 1 byte, and `fgets()` must store a null terminator into the destination.

For the second case: `fgets(firstDigit, 2, stdin);` reads 1 byte from `stdin`, the digit that you typed, and cannot read the newline because the destination array is already full, allowing for the null terminator.  The second `fgets()` reads the pending newline from the first entry and returns immediately for the same reason, not letting you type the second input.

You must allow `fgets()` to read at least 2 bytes by providing a buffer size of at least 3:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char firstDigit[3];
    char secondDigit[3];

    printf("Enter your first digit: ");
    if (!fgets(firstDigit, sizeof firstDigit, stdin))
        return 1;
    printf("\nEnter your second digit: ");
    if (!fgets(secondDigit, sizeof secondDigit, stdin))
        return 1;
    printf("\n\nYour first digit is %s and your second digit is %s.\n",
           firstDigit, secondDigit);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that if you type more than a single character before the enter key, the program will still behave in an unexpected way.

Answer (score 0):

This is a buffer problem. When you press enter, don't know why it is saved in the stdin buffer.
After you perform an `fgets(...)` you must type `fflush(stdin);` on all circumstances.

Something like this:

```
printf("Enter your first digit: ");
fgets(firstDigit, 1, stdin);
fflush(stdin);
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170410/what-is-the-use-of-fflushstdin-in-c-programming)

Comment: @yano Well, we can alternatively use "getchar();" to consume that newline.

Comment: See [Using `fflush(stdin)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin) — it is often not appropriate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler as I told yano, we can alternatively use getchar(); to solve this.

Comment: Yes, so you commented.  You haven't yet added that to your answer, though.  Comments are ephemeral; answers aren't.  And your answer still shows dubious practice.  After reading either or both of the links, you could add some material to your answer — noting that if you're on Windows you might be OK using `fflush(stdin)`, but on Unix-like systems, you won't achieve anything useful.  And then add the robust alternative.  Note that if `fgets()` reads the newline, you won't want to gobble the input with `getchar()`, so you have to check what you got from `fgets()`.