# How to check if user input numbers instead of string(array of char) in C

Tags: c, arrays

So, I got this assignment as a student that ask me to create a simple program using C.
This program input only allow you to input only characters `A`-`Z`, `a`-`z`, and (space).
and the length of the string should be no less than 1 character and no more than 100 characters.

So, I come with the conclusion that I should use `if` function to validate if the user input the allowed character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char name[100];

    scanf("%s",&name);
    fflush(stdin);
    if (isdigit(name))
                ^^^^
    {
        printf("Wrong answers");    
        getchar();
    }
    else
        ....
```

It was supposed to print `"wrong answers"` if you input numbers in there, but this program won't run.. It keeps saying  :

> error C2664: 'isdigit' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [100]' to 'int'

I don't know what this error means.. Is there something I miss? Or am I using the wrong function?

I have also tried

```
if (((name>='A')&&(name<='Z'))||((name>='a')&&(name<='z')||)((name==' ')))
{
  //this print what i want
}
else
{
  printf("wrong answers");//this print "wrong answer"
}
```

but it always print `"wrong answers"` no matter I input the correct input or the wrong input.

Your help is highly appreciated.
Thank you.

*ps : I am a beginner at programming.

Comment: The type of `name` is an array of `char`, while `isdigit()` expects a single `char`.

Comment: Note that `fflush(stdin);` is non-portable and is actually explicitly undefined behavior.  Per **7.21.5.2  The `fflush` function**, paragraph 2 of [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):  "If
`stream`
points  to  an  output  stream  or  an  update  stream  in  which  the  most  `recent`
operation was not input, the
`fflush`
function causes any unwritten data for that stream
to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; **otherwise, the behavior is
undefined**."

Comment: Before using a particular function, it might be wise to [RTFM](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isdigit).

Comment: Your caps lock key is broken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isdigit()` takes an `int` as argument, not a `char*`:

```
   int isdigit(int c);
```

You have to use a loop over the string and check each character in it.

Having said that, to achieve:

> this program input only allow you to input only characters 'A'-'Z', 'a'-'z', and ' '(space)

you are better off using `isalpha()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char name[101], temp;

    // take input one character at a time    
    while(scanf("%c", &temp)){
        // stop when newline or carriage return
        if(temp == '\n' || temp == '\0' || !isalpha(temp) ){
            break;
        }

        // save character in array
        name[i] = temp;

        // move to the next position of the array
        i++;
    }

    printf( "%s", temp );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're seeing is that you're passing `isdigit` the wrong type of value - it expects an `int`, but you're passing it an array of `char`. You would have to loop over each and every character in your string to check if it's a digit or not.

But that is ultimately not what you're after as you're looking to confirm that the string contains letters or spaces - there are lots of characters that could be entered that aren't classed as digits that would be accepted incorrectly.

What would be the easiest solution for you, is to use the function `strspn`. It takes a string and returns the length of how many characters match the second parameter. If that length is the same length as your string, you know that it only contains valid characters.

```
size_t valid;
valid=strspn(name, "abcdefg(fill in with other valid characters)");
if(valid==strlen(name))
  {
  // Valid name
  }
else
  {
  // Not valid
  }
```

If you need to expand the accepted characters, it's just a simple case of adding them to the 2nd parameter.

Answer (score 0):

OP's code fails as `isdigit()` test is a single *character* is a digit (0-9).  It does not test a string.

> `int isdigit(int c);`
>   The `isdigit` function tests for any decimal-digit character.
>   In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be
>   representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`.

OP's buffer is too small to save 100 characters read from the user.  At least 1 more needed to detect if too many were read and 1 more for a *null character* to mark the end of a *string*.

`fflush(stdin);` has its [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170410/what-is-the-use-of-fflushstdin-in-c-programming) too.

`scanf("%s",&name);` does not save white-space.  The parameter should have been `name` too.  (no `&`)

---

Read a *line* of user input with `fgets()` which saves the result as a *string*. 
 Test if the input meets the criteria.

**Read**

```
#define N 100
// No need to be stingy on buffer size reading user input.  Suggest 2x
// We need +1 for extra character detection, \n and \0
char buf[2*N + 1 + 1];
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
// lop off potential \n
size_t length = strlen(buf);
if (length > 0 && buf[length-1] == '\n') {
  buf[--length] = '\0';
}
```

**Test**

1. only characters 'A'-'Z', 'a'-'z', and ' '(space).

   ```
   for (size_t i = 0; i<length; i++) {
     if (!isalpha((unsigned char)buf[i]) && buf[i] != ' ') {
       puts("Invalid chracter");
       break;
     }
   }
   ```
2. length of the string should be no less than 1 character and no more than 100 characters.

   ```
   if (length < 1 || length > 100) {
     puts("Input wrong length");
   }
   ```

Others approaches can be used to disqualify *very long* inputs.  IMO, *very long* inputs represent an attack and should be handled differently than a simple line that was a bit too long.

```
    if (length < 1 || length > 100) {
      if (length + 2 >= sizeof buf) {
        puts("Input way too long");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      puts("Input wrong length");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`name` must have one extra space for the `\0` (`NUL`) character.
So to store 100 characters, its size should be at least 101.

```
char name[101];
```

You could first use

```
fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
```

to read into `name` character array.

Note that `fgets()` will read in the trailing newline (`\n`) as well which need be removed like

```
name[strlen(name)-1]='\0';
```

Then use `sscanf()`. Like

```
size_t l=strlen(name);
sscanf(name, "%100[A-Za-z ]", name);

if(strlen(name)!=l)
{
    printf("\nInvalid input.");
}
```

Note the space after the `A-Za-z`.

The `100` in the `%100[A-Za-z]` denotes reading at most 100 characters into `name`. The `[A-Za-z ]` will make the `sscanf()` stop reading if a non-alphabetic character which is not a space is encountered.

First read into `name`. Then store its length in `l`. Now read everything till a non-alphabet other than a space occurs in `name` to `name` itself (thereby modifying `name`). 
Now compare the length of this new string with `l`. If they are the same. The input is valid as per your need.

You could also use `scanf()` instead of `fgets()` like

```
scanf("%100[^\n]", name);
```

which instructs to read every character till a `\n` into `name`. If this is used, no `\n` will added at the end of `name` unlike the case with `fgets()`.

Now I would like to point out some mistakes in your code.

```
scanf("%s",&name);
```

will lead to errors. Correct one is

```
scanf("%s",name);
```

as the second argument here must be an address and since an array name in C decays into its base address, just `name` would do instead of `&name`.

As others have pointed out, using `fflush()` on `stdin` is undefined and must be avoided.

If you are trying to clear the input buffer till the next newline (`\n`), you could do

```
int ch;
while((ch=getchar())!='\n');// && ch!=EOF)
```

The argument of `isdigit()` must be a `char` and not a character array (type `char [100]` if size is 100).

And `if` is a statement and *not* a function.