# Error :"pointer being realloc'd was not allocated" on macOS but works on Windows when trying to realloc twice

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, realloc

I'm trying to implement a function that concatenate two strings, but I keep getting the same error.
"pointer being realloc'd was not allocated"
When I compiled the same code on a windows machine it worked, is it something that I'm missing?
The code below is basically what I'm trying to do.
main:

```
int main() {

int length = 4096;
char *string = malloc(length * sizeof(char));
createString(string, length);
realloc(string, 30);
return 0;
}
```

createString:

```
void createString(char * string, int length) {
  char *copyAdress = string;
  char *temp ="";
  int counter2 = 0;

  fflush(stdin);
  fgets(string, length,stdin);
  while(*string != EOF && *string != *temp ) {
    string++;
    counter++;
  }
  string = copyAdress;
  realloc(string, (counter)*sizeof(char));
}
```

Thanks!
Edit:
I want createString to change the size of string to the length of the string that I get with fgets, while having the same address as the string that I sent in, so I can allocate more memory to it later when I want to add another string to it.

Comment: `*string != *temp ` is just comparing with `'\0'` because `temp` is `""`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's work through this in order of execution.

`fflush(stdin);` is [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18170435/4961259). If you really need to clear everything in the stdin you have to find another way (a loop for example). There are compilers/systems with a defined implementation but I would not count on it.

`string++;` is superflous as you overwrite `string` after the loop.

```
realloc(string, (counter)*sizeof(char));
```

should be

```
char *temp = realloc(string, (counter)*sizeof(char));
if (temp != NULL)
  string = temp;
```

This way you get the pointer where your new `string` is located, but I suggest you read the refecerence for [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc). In essence you do not know if it has been moved and the old address might be invalid from that point on. So dereferencing it is also undefined behaviour.

After this you would have to return the new address of `string` or pass the address of the pointer to your function.

The same problem repeats with the second `realloc`. You only got to know your first call was wrong, because the second call noticed that you do not have valid data in what you thought would be your `string`.

---

In regards to your comment: It is not possible to use `realloc` and to be sure that the reallocated memory is in the same place as before.

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues:

1. `realloc(string, (counter)*sizeof(char));` is wrong, you need `string = realloc(string, (counter)*sizeof(char));` because `realloc` **may** return a different address.
2. Calling `createString(string, length);` won't modify `string`

If you want a more accurate answer you need to tell us what *exactly*  `createString` is supposed to do. In your code there is no attempt to concatenate two strings.

Comment: My goal is to change the size of the string in main with createString while having the same address as before. Then I want to add more space to the string, so I can concatenate another string to it.

Comment: ...and `realloc` may return 0 if it can;t realloc, so `tmpstring= realloc(...`

Answer (score 1):

If you `realloc` some memory, the pointer pointing to the original memory becomes invalid (unless `realloc` failed and returned `NULL`). So calling `realloc` twice on the same pointer should indeed not work (if it didn't return `NULL` the first time).

Comment: It doesn not _need_ to become invalid of realloc could expand the memory. It _may_, though.

Answer (score 0):

See the answers from others about what you do wrong. However, the eror message means that on MacOS, the `realloc` in `createString` deallocated the orignal `string` and allocated a new one, and now your `realloc` in `main` tries to `realloc` a pointer that is no longer valid (allocated). On Windows, the memory was not deallocated in `createString` and so the second call of `realloc` (in `main`) is given a valid pointer.