# Problem with functions calling each other?

Tags: c

I'm new cs student, i've only been studying for less than two months now so please bear with me. This is also my very first question here on Stackoverflow, I would greatly appreciate if someone help me with this problem.

So, I have made a function that receives input from the user.

```
1| int getInput()
2| {
3|     int x;
4|     fflush(stdin);
5|     printf("Enter amount: ");
6|     scanf("%d%*c", &x);
7|     validate(x);
8|    return x;
9| }
```

After getting input an input from the user, it calls *validate()* function to do input validation.

```
10| void validate(int x)
11| {
12|     bool valid = false;
13|     do
14|     {
15|         if ((x >= 5) && (x <= 95) && (x % 5 == 0))
16|         {
17|             printf("Amount accepted!");
18|             valid = true;
19|         }
20|         else
21|         {
22|             printf("Invalid input");
23|             askQuit();
24|             getInput();
25|         }
26|     } while (valid == false);
27|     return;
28| }
```

If the user entered a valid input, it breaks the loop then go back to main to proceed. But if the input is not valid, it calls another function *askQuit()* to ask the user if they want to terminate the program.

```
29| void askQuit()
30| {
31|     char quit;
32|     do
33|     {
34|         fflush(stdin);
35|         printf("Would you like to quit? y/n: ");
36|         scanf("%c%*c", &quit);
37|     
38|         tolower(quit);
39|         switch (quit)
40|         {
41|             case 'y':
42|                 exit(0);
43|             case 'n':
44|                 break;
45|             default:
46|                 printf("Invalid input. Try Again.");
47|         }
48|     } while(quit != 'n');
49|     return;
50| }
```

If the user don't want to continue, program gets terminated. But if they continue, it breaks the loop and returns to proceed in **line 24** to call the *getInput()* function to ask for user input again.

The whole program works perfectly fine when a valid input entered the first time. But if we enter an invalid input, the next time we enter a correct input is where the problem arise. It tends to execute both if and else statements inside the *validate()* function. Why does this happen? I spent hours trying to analyze why the program behave this way, but I can't seem to think of a reason.

If someone can explain it to me I would be very grateful! Thanks!

Comment: Why are you are ignoring the return value from getInput?

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` [is undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18170410/2302862).

Comment: your idea to use getInput to call validate and then to have validate call getInput is faulty. Walk through this code with 1 faulty input and 1 good input and see what happens.

Comment: @johnelemans  Yes! that's how I found the problem. But even though I know the problem, I still couldn't figure out why it behave the way it does.

Comment: @stark I seriously haven't notice that! I think I overlooked that part because I made the getInput() originally to use in main() only. Thanks for calling that out!

Comment: if you don't understand why it behaves the way it does, you haven't walked the code. Tell us what happens when you enter faulty input, step by step.

Comment: @johnelemans I followed your advice and I have found out what exactly the problem was. Thank you!