# How to add predefined data into a nested structure

Tags: c

[This is the output I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLNfW.png). This is what I've got so far. I've only been able to figure out how to add 1 subject, but I need to add 2 more like the picture. I tried to save directly into the array but it didn't work. So i used strcpy.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {    
 char subjectID[10];  
 char subjectName[10]; 
 float marks;    
}Subject;        
  
typedef struct {   
 char Stu_ID[10];  
 char Stu_Name[30]; 
 Subject subjects; 
}Student;      

int main()
{
 Student a[3]; 
 Student b;   
 int i;     

 strcpy(b.Stu_ID, "S100011");
 strcpy(b.Stu_Name, "James");
 strcpy(b.subjects.subjectID, "TOS10005");
 strcpy(b.subjects.subjectName, "Programming");
 b.subjects.marks=50;

 printf("Student details \n"); 
 printf("ID : %s\t Name : %s\n\n", b.Stu_ID, b.Stu_Name);         
 printf("Subject ID\t Name\t\t Marks\n");
 printf("%s\t %s\t\t %.2f\t \n",  b.subjects.subjectID, b.subjects.subjectName, b.subjects.marks);
}
```

Comment: Have you considered making `Student::subjects` into an array?

Comment: first problem I see, `strcpy(b.subjects.subjectName, "Programming");`, the `subjectName` field is only 10 long, but `"Programming"` is 12 long (including `NUL` terminator). Overwriting the buffer invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), no point in trying to make sense of what your program does after that. Memory is cheap, make those 64 long at least. But you'll always need to make sure not overrun buffers.

Comment: also, `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior. Not sure why @BillLynch removed that in an edit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170410/what-is-the-use-of-fflushstdin-in-c-programming

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Please don't post screenshots of text, copy the text verbatim into your question.