# Problem in storing data dynamically in linked list

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that reads a maximum of 8 bank account information and store them dynamically in a linked list. I wrote a function to calculate the average of all the entered bank accounts' balances but when I try to call that function no output is produced. can you please help me figure out where the problem is?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

//node structure
typedef struct node {
   int no;
   char name[20];
   float total;
   struct node * nextptr;
}
account;

//int for division of total to find the average
static int t;

//adding accounts function
account * addaccount(account * temp) {
   fflush(stdin);
   printf("Enter the account name: \n");
   gets(temp -> name);
   printf("Enter the account number: \n");
   scanf("%d", & temp -> no);
   printf("Enter the account balance: \n");
   scanf("%f", & temp -> total);
   t++; // used for finding the average 
   return temp;
}

// function for calculating the average
float sum(account * temp) {
   float average = 1.0, sum = 0.0;
   int i;
   account * start;
   temp = start;
   for (i = 0; i < t; i++) {
      sum += temp -> total;
      temp = temp -> nextptr;
   }
   average = sum / t;
   return average;
}

int main() {
   int selection;
   account * start = NULL;
   account * save, * temp;
   account * ptr;
   ptr = (account * ) malloc(sizeof(account) * 8);
   do {
      //Menu
      printf("\n1.Adding account\n");
      printf("2.Find the average of the added accounts' balances\n");
      printf("3.Exit\n");
      scanf("%d", & selection);
      switch (selection) {
      case 1: {
         if (ptr == NULL)
            ptr = (account * ) realloc(ptr, sizeof(account));
         save = addaccount(ptr);
         if (start == NULL) {
            start = save;
            start -> nextptr = NULL;
         } else {
            temp = start;
            while (temp -> nextptr != NULL)
               temp = temp -> nextptr;
            temp -> nextptr = save;
            save -> nextptr = NULL;
         }
         break;
      }
      case 2: {
         float avg;
         avg = sum(temp);
         printf("%f", avg);
         break;
      }
      case 3: {
         temp = start;
         while (temp != NULL) {
            free(temp);
            temp = temp -> nextptr;
         }
         break;
      }
      }
   } while (selection != 4);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn to debug your own code. Run your program in a debugger and trace the program flow and variable values as it runs. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Please fix your code indentation. Also, you're essentially pre-allocating space for all 8 accounts in an array. Either do this and then use simple array indexing instead of the linked list or ditch the idea of pre-allocating all 8 and allocate them one-by-one as needed (which is what you would do in a real linked list).

Comment: Mustafa, Who or what text suggested using `fflush(stdin);`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Probably to discard a `\n` left behind by `scanf("%d", &selection);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau No doubt.  [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72051493/problem-in-storing-data-dynamically-in-linked-list?noredirect=1#comment127311908_72051493) still remains.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Our professor in university suggested it.

Comment: @Mustafa Note that [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2410359) is no longer part of C and `fflush(stdin)` has its [troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18170435/2410359).  Gauge your instruction accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a number of problems with your code:

- you say you want a *maximum* of 8 `account`s, but there is no such limit being imposed by the code.
- in `sum()` (which is misnamed, BTW), you are not looping through the nodes correctly, because the `temp = start;` assignment is backwards. `start` is *uninitialized*, and then `temp` is used inside the loop, thus invoking *undefined behavior*. You don't actually need the `start` variable at all, since you can simply increment the `account* temp` parameter.
- in `main()`, you are initially pointing `ptr` to an array of 8 `account`s, but if the user enters `1` on your menu, and `ptr` is `NULL` (which it would not be unless that initial `malloc()` failed), then you are pointing `ptr` to a single `account`.  If your goal is to allow the user to enter an arbitrary number of `account`s, your list management is all wrong.

  Worse, every time the user enters `1` on your menu, you are calling `addaccount()` on the 1st `account` in the array, and `addaccount()` simply populates the specified `account` with data.  So, you are not actually creating a new `account` and adding it to the list, at all.  You are just linking the 1st `account` back to itself, over and over.
- if the user enters `2` on your menu, you are calling `sum()` on the *last* `account` created by `1`.  If no `account` has been created yet, your code will crash since `temp` is *uninitialized* at that point. You need to call the function on the *first* `account` instead, so it can iterate the whole list.
- if the user enters `3` on your menu, the code tries to `free()` individual `account`s, but you did not actually `malloc()` individual `account`s to begin with.  You are trying to store `account`s in an array instead, so you would just need to `free()` the array instead.

  Also, your loop is checking for `selection != 4`, but your menu doesn't have an option `4`.  You should be checking for `selection != 3` instead.

With that said, try something more like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//node structure
typedef struct node {
   int no;
   char name[20];
   float total;
   struct node * nextptr;
}
account;

//adding accounts function
account* addaccount() {
   account *temp = malloc(sizeof(account));
   if (temp == NULL) {
      printf("Unable to create new account\n");
      return NULL;
   }
   fflush(stdin);
   printf("Enter the account name: \n");
   gets(temp->name);
   printf("Enter the account number: \n");
   scanf("%d", &temp->no);
   printf("Enter the account balance: \n");
   scanf("%f", &temp->total);
   temp->nextptr = NULL;
   return temp;
}

// function for calculating the average
float average(account* start) {
   if (start == NULL) return 0.0;
   float sum = 0.0;
   int t = 0;
   do {
      sum += start->total;
      start = start->nextptr;
      ++t;
   }
   while (start != NULL);
   return sum / t;
}

int main() {
   int selection;
   account *start = NULL, *last = NULL, *temp;

   do {
      //Menu
      printf("1.Adding account\n");
      printf("2.Find the average of the added accounts' balances\n");
      printf("3.Exit\n");
      scanf("%d", &selection);
      switch (selection) {
         case 1: {
            if ((temp = addaccount()) == NULL) break;
            if (start == NULL)
               start = temp;
            else
               last->nextptr = temp;
            last = temp;
            break;
         }
         case 2: {
            printf("%f\n", average(start));
            break;
         }
      }
   } while (selection != 3);

   temp = start;
   while (temp != NULL) {
      free(temp);
      temp = temp -> nextptr;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Look here

```
// function for calculating the average
float sum(account* temp) {
    float average = 1.0, sum = 0.0;
    int i;
    account* start; <<<==== a random value
    temp = start;   <<<=== over write the parameter of this function with a random value
    for (i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        sum += temp->total;
        temp = temp->nextptr;
    }
    average = sum / t;
    return average;
}
```

Not sure what you are trying to do here - but that is for sure wrong

Comment: That's exactly where the problem was, I had to assign the start pointer value to the temp pointer from the main function not from inside the sum function. It's working now thank you.