# scanf a integer but store as float

Tags: c, floating-point, integer, scanf

This is my code:

```
float pi = 3.1415;
float radius, area;

printf("Type the radius of you circle:");
scanf("%f,&radius");
fflush(stdin);

area=radius*radius*pi;

printf("The area of the circle with radius %f is:%f",radius, area);

return 0;
```

I have a float for PI, for the radius and for the area that will be calculated. The code will ask the user for the radius and then calculate the area.

**The problem is:** If the user type the radius as a integer, so for example "10" nothing works. I want the user to be able to type both integers and floats as the radius, so both "10" and "10.5" for example. How do I make that work? How can I storage a integer input as a float?

Comment: `scanf("%f,&radius");` I cannot believe that doesn't flag all sort of compiler warnings. Look at that carefully. `, &radius` shouldn't be *in* the format string. Unrelated, whatever resource told you to use `fflush(stdin);` paddle away from it from now on; that invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: You have a typo: it should be `scanf("%f",&radius);`

Comment: Enable warnings and check your `scanf` parameters.

Comment: Thank you guys! The problem was the typo. I'm new to C and that helped a lot!! 
My college professor told me to use fflush(stdin) but now that you said that I'll look deeper into it, it's not the first time I see someone saying its bad.

Thanks again! =)

Comment: And what happens when the user types "five"??? `radius` is uninitialised, and could/will give the floating point library heartburn... If you are going to ignore the return value from `scanf()`, at least initialise `float radius = 0.0, area;`....

Comment: See [What is the use of fflush(stdin) in c programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170410/what-is-the-use-of-fflushstdin-in-c-programming)

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggested, **the problem was a typo**:

`scanf("%f,&radius");` **should be** `scanf("%f",&radius);`

Fixing the typo made the code work! Thank you so much for the people who commented!

Comment: _A_ problem was a typo. _The_ problem was compiling without all warnings enabled.  Save time, enable them all and get rapid feedback like "warning: format '%f' expects a matching 'float *' argument [-Wformat=]".

Comment: How do I enable them? I tought they were enabled by default like in other langagues I've used in the past

Comment: To enable all warnings varies by compiler.  I suggest searching for "enable all warnings" and your compiler name.